# How to get count of active category children - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, category

Now I receive children number using this code:

```
$currentCategory = $this->getCurrentCategory();
$childrenCount = $currentCategory->getChildrenCount();
```

But it counts both enabled and disabled children.

Do you know method that counts only enabled children, or I have to filter them in block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use like,

```
$currentCategory = $this->getCurrentCategory();
$childCategory=$currentCategory->getChildrenCategories()->addIsActiveFilter();
echo count($childCategory);
```

Comment: Just in case you can also call count as method `$childCategory->count();`!

Comment: If you only care about the number of categories, you should better use `$childCategory->getSize()` to not load the full collection.